# Custom init while creating view with storyboard or programmatically

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, subclass, init

I am trying to create a subclass of UIViewController and then through the storyboard or programmatically pass data to it. What I have tried so far is to have a subViewController swift file with a class subViewController that is a UIViewController

```
import UIKit

class subViewController: UIViewController {

    var s1 = String()

    init(myString: String) {

        self.s1 = myString
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print(self.s1)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

then in Identity Inspector I connect this to the view controller

and in AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let SubVC = subViewController(myString: "Komic")

    self.window?.rootViewController = SubVC

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

This loads a black screen but it logs out myString. As far as I understand it doesn't create the view but it just creates the instance of the class and that's why it's giving me the black screen. I also know that this part

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

runs when the storyboard gives you the view. But I can't pass data in there that's why I am trying to do this programmaticaly. Is it possible somehow to do that? I know I could instantiateWithIdentifier with the storyboard but I can't find a way to pass my data through that....any help?

Answer (score 2):

An (ugly) way to solve this issue:

You can set your `var s1` from an external buffer in your code (AppDelegate variable in this example)

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.s1 = UIApplication.shared().delegate.bufferForS1

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

And when you initiate your UIViewController through Storyboard:

```
UIApplication.shared().delegate.bufferForS1 = myS1Value
self.navigationController!.pushViewControllerFading(self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myViewControllerID") as UIViewController)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not loading the view controller from the storyboard when you call your custom initialiser, if you create a customer initialiser it is your responsibility to create the view hierarchy programatically - typically in loadView() although lots of people do it in viewDidLoad().

In Order to the load the view hierarchy  you defined in the storyboard you can do this:

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardName", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("storyboardId")
```

You define the storyboard Id of a view controller in the identity inspector

Comment: I don't see how I could pass data using this. If I create the storyboard and the instantiate the View Controller then my custom init doesn't run, right? So either I have to create my view hierarchy in loadView() (I don't know how to do that yet) or load my view using the storyboard (and not pass any data).

Comment: Yeah this is (imo) one of the disadvantages of using storyboards/Nibs is that you cant inject any values into your view controller on initialisation because the initialisation is done by the framework. Typically you set these properties after creation here or if using segues in the prepareForSegue method. In swift this presents a problem are have to be either optional or implicitly unwrapped optional properties

Comment: I see...This is a problem indeed because what happens if I want a superclass that all my classes inherit from so I can access anything that I want everywhere in the app? :(

Comment: @MichaelKornelakis did you find something that solve your issue? I am in your situation currently.

Comment: @Tulleb it's been a while now and I don't even remember exactly what I wanted to do back then! :) But if I understand correctly, what I do is to instantiate my view controller and then pass the data and after that I it as view controller. I will try to write an answer for this later. :)

Comment: @MichaelKornelakis I just found a solution and answered just above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38594044/2854405.